# Enter key enable using knockout and javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

i have an html textbox with onkeypress event to send message like below

```
<input type="text" data-bind="attr:{id: 'txtDim' +  $data.userID, onkeypress: $root.sendMsg('#txtDim' +  $data.userID, $data)}" />
```

I have written javascript function to to send message while preesing enter button like below:

```
self.sendMsg = function (id, data) {
    $(id).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            //method called to send message
            //self.SendDIM(data);
        }
    });
};
```

In my case i have to press enter button 2 times to send the message.
1: keypress call self.sendMsg
2: keypress call self.SendDIM

But i need to send message on one keypress only. It can be done in plain javascript only. But i need viewmodel data, so applied in data-bind. So not working fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have added keypress event like below to textbox

```
 <input type="text" data-bind="attr:{id: 'txtGoalsheetNote' +  $data.userID}, event:{keypress: $root.SendMsg}" />
```

And in javascript i have added the following method by keeping event as a parameter

```
 self.SendMsg= function (data, event) {
    try {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            //call method here
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (e)
{ }
}
```

Then its work.

Comment: That directly binds you VM to your UI, its generally considered an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 17):

The reason you need to press enter twice is that your `sendMsg` method is only attaching a handler to the `keydown` event.  This handler is then invoked on the second button press.

A better approach would be to write a custom binding handler that attaches the event handler and passes the view model through:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.returnAction = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {

    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

    $(element).keydown(function(e) {
      if (e.which === 13) {
        value(viewModel);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

You can see a [running example here](http://jsfiddle.net/stevegreatrex/UNJWj/)

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. I had was having to press enter twice until I notice valueUpdate: 'afterkeyup' in the jsFidde.

Comment: This is the more correct solution than what the OP posted as his answer, this worked for me and seems to be the 'right' way to do it.

Comment: Excellent. A sugggestion I would make is to use "value(viewModel, e)" on the last line of alphabet-writing-code. So that the consuming function has access to the event object. Regardless, thanks for the code and you helped me solve a problem.

Comment: I think I like [this approach](http://blog.outsharked.com/2013/05/adding-default-enter-key-handling-to.html) a little better. It allows you to set the enter key binding on an ancestor of the input, select, textarea. That way, you don't have to repeat the binding on each input, select, textarea.
On the other hand, if you want that fine-grained control, this will work. **However,** note that the element that has focus when ENTER is pressed may not update your VM unless you first blur() it, or you have to use something like `valueUpdate: 'afterkeyup'` on all of your bound form elements.